# Cookie does not send when i deploy the resful api that created by nestjs to azure web app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, nestjs, express-session

I have a RestApi authentication system that use express-session.

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(
        session({
          secret: 'sdfsdfsdfsdjfksdjf',
          saveUninitialized: false,
          resave: true,
          cookie: {
            maxAge: 3600000 * 24 * 10,
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: true,
            domain: 'https://nestback.azurewebsites.net',
            path: '/',
          },
          store: new MongodbStore({
            uri: 'mongodb+srv://AmirM:Dana1400@cluster0.7mygx.mongodb.net/GRADEGYDB',
            collection: 'mySessions',
          }),
        }),

        passport.initialize(),
        passport.session(),
      )
      .forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

and

```
app.enableCors({
    origin: ['https://gradegyadmin.azurewebsites.net'],
    credentials: true,
  });
```

the 'https://gradegyadmin.azurewebsites.net' is my client and https://nestback.azurewebsites.net is my backend server

when I deploy on the web app azure service the cookie does not send.
how can I fixed that

i tried to change cookie setting

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the above code that which you provided. please try the below one.

```
cookie: {
  maxAge: 3600000 * 24 * 10,
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  domain: 'nestback.azurewebsites.net',
  path: '/',
  sameSite: 'none',
},
```

- You need to set the `sameSite` attribute to `none` only if you are using a third-party cookie. Also, you need to expose the `set-cookie` header in the CORS settings to allow the client application to receive the cookie.

Here I tried a simple basic API nest.js app. by GET, SET, DELETE endpoints. Its working fine in local.

Installed `npm install cookie-parser`.

[image]

- Deployed to app service and make sure Enable the CORS.

[image]

- Iam able to Get in local as well as cloud.

[image]

[image]